# ASP.NET Identity 2.0 Get RoleNames in a dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I want role names in a dropdown list but, my code puts this in instead: **System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.IdentityRole_9242DF3B1E41249C78E71E10BE06DC7180880D3BD461D49C4D7FA49EA1C455CA**

```
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>());
        var roles = roleManager.Roles.ToList();

        DropDownList1.DataSource = roles;
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

i feel this is very simple error i dont see.

Thank Jeremy Cook for the right answare.

New Code

```
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>());
        var roles = roleManager.Roles.ToList();
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Id";
        DropDownList1.DataSource = roles;
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `IdentityRole` does not override `ToString()`, so you are seeing the class name instead. [See the source here.](http://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/2.0.0-beta1-140130/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityRole.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework)

However, setting the `DataTextField` property to "Name" should sidestep your trouble. (You may also want to set the `DataValueField` property to "Id".)

Comment: This doesn't seem to have  to do with the override of ToString(). If there's a data source with a number of data fields you have to specify which one is to be bound as the text field of the drop down list and optionally which one as the value field, otherwise the control won't know which field to bind to.